# What is meaning of "Sulking though"?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

The background story is as follows. Author flunked engineering entrance exam. He took tuitions by paying hefty fee from his father pockets in order to crack the exam. How ever he flunked again. After results he had scolded and reprimanded by his father. Then author went out from home to take a break. And now he is returning to home.

> I walk back home. The one-hour walk in the fresh air made me feel better temporarily. I should not talk to Baba(Father) about expensive private colleges, I thought. May be I should talk him about me making money in a job rather than spending more. First, I would have to end his **sulking though**.

What is the meaning of **Sulking though** here?

I know the meaning of **though** is *despite the fact that*. But the literal meaning ('*First, I would have to end his bad tempered silence despite the fact that*') seems to be meaningless.

Comment: I'm sure OP asked this question in good faith, and did actually do at least *some* prior research. I'm still voting to close as General Reference though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/though) has this use of *though* meaning *however*:

> however (indicating that a factor qualifies or imposes restrictions on what was said previously):
>     *I was hunting for work. Jobs were scarce though.*

...which exactly parallels your sentence. You can rewrite it

> I was hunting for work, but jobs were scarce,

and the same construction can be used in your example:

> But first, I would have to end his sulking.

Comment: I think OPs example (and probably ODOs) is mispunctuated. *First, though, I would have to end his sulking* becomes *First I would have to end his sulking, though.*

Comment: Yes, I think I would use a comma, too. But it's not my place to misquote/correct ODO.